# Omnifaces viewscoped bean is recreated over and over

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cdi, omnifaces

I'm trying to implement ViewScoped CDI bean using Omnifaces. Bean method that populates list with search results for primefaces datatable gets called using ajax from jsf page. If bean scope is set to session everything works correctly. When i try to set scope to Omnifaces ViewScope, container starts to create and destroy bean over and over many times without any reason. Here is the bean code:

```
...
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class FindClientBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ClientDAO clientDAO;    
@NotNull(message="Search string cannot be empty")   
private String searchString;
private List<Client> resultList;    

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("init");
}

@PreDestroy
public void end() {
    System.out.println("end");
}

public void findClient() {
    System.out.println("method");
    resultList = clientDAO.findClientByNameOrLastnamePart(searchString);
}

//Getters and setters..    

}
```

Sample output (there are many more inits and ends for one method call, i skipped them):

```
01:51:50,044 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) init

01:51:50,044 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-4) init

01:51:50,044 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) end

01:51:50,045 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-4) end

01:51:50,045 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) init

01:51:50,045 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-4) init

01:51:50,046 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) end

01:51:50,046 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-4) method

01:51:50,047 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) init

01:51:50,047 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) end

01:51:50,048 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) init

01:51:50,048 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) end

01:51:50,049 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) init

01:51:50,049 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-9090-5) end
```

What it can be? Haven't found relevant question. 
My configuration: JBoss AS 7.1, Omnifaces 1.6.3, Primefaces 4.0

Comment: What action are you doing client side?

Comment: Which AS 7.1 subversion exactly? 7.1.0? Thus, with Mojarra 2.1.5? And, does the problem disappear when you use `@ManagedBean @ViewScoped` from `javax.faces.bean` package?

Comment: Alexandre: I'm trying to populate primefaces datatable using search string via ajax request from database.

Comment: @BalusC: I'm using AS 7.1.1 with Mojarra JSF 2.1.7. When i use ManagedBean ViewScoped, everything works correctly.

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem with JBoss EAP 6.0.1

Comment: Cass and @Gandalf: Sorry, I'm unable to reproduce this problem in both AS 7.1.1 and EAP 6.1.1 (don't have 6.0.1 at hands) in their default trim with a barebones JSF-CDI project. There's likely more at matter in your CDI configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Reason it didnt work for me was, that in my Project Properties -> Project Facets was Dynamic Web Project of version 3.0

but in web.xml was project saved as 2.5

so I just changed  2.5 to 3.0 to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>zjazdi</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```